# How do I arrange events in useEffect in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In main Application file (App.js) I have this code, the `<button>` here can unmount the "Dropdown" component

```
return (
    <div>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          console.log("App button"); // First
          setShowDropDown(!showDropDown);
        }}
      >
        Toggle Dropdown
      </button>
      {showDropDown ? (
        <Dropdown
          selected={selected}
          onSelectedChange={setSelected}
          options={options}
        />
      ) : null}
    </div>
  );
```

In Dropdown component file (Dropdown.js) This event `onBodyClick` make the Dropdown menu not active when click on any place unless the Dropdown menu itself.
The goal here is to cancel the event by Cleanup function in `useEffect` when I click on the button. The problem is : when I click the button, the order of what happened is something like that :

- First : The button `onClick` event and "unmounting".
- Second : The `onBodyClick` event.
- Finally : Cleanup.
  This order makes a problem when I clicked on the button, That's because the event happening after unmounting. How can I solve that?
  the error: Cannot read property 'contains' of null

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const onBodyClick = (event) => {
      console.log("event");   // Second
      if (ref.current.contains(event.target)) {
        return;
      }
      setOpen(false);
    };
    document.body.addEventListener("click", onBodyClick);
    return () => {
      console.log("cleanup");  // Finally
      document.body.removeEventListener("click", onBodyClick);
    };
  }, []);
```

Comment: Cannot read property 'contains' of null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you just need to check if the ref exists first:

```
const onBodyClick = (event) => {
  if (!ref.current) {
    // Component is unmounting
    // below line could be used or commented out; since the component is unmounting,
    // the state should not make a difference
    // setOpen(false);
    return
  }
  if (ref.current.contains(event.target)) {
    // Component is not unmounting, and click was inside ref
    return;
  }
  // Component is not unmounting, and click was outside ref
  setOpen(false);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem and this is working for me

```js
if(this.wrapperRef && !this.wrapperRef.contains(event.target) {
 this.setState({visibility: false});
}
```

I check if wrapperRef exists and I check if the wrapper contains the Html element

I know you are using react hooks, but the idea is the same.